# D3 transform transition "null parsing transform attribute"

Tags: d3.js

The basic problem is that I have a drag event on a path that transitions the path a certain distance in the x axis.

When another event happens I want to return the path back to its original position before the drag event.

I tried to do this with the below code:

```
svg.select('#' + uniqueid + '-flare')
                    .select('path')
                    .transition().duration(1000)
                    .ease('linear')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)');
```

This is giving me the warning  "null parsing transform attribute" and the SVG container in the HTML shows transform="".

Using this following code works perfectly well, but is choppy. I want the smooth animation provided by the transition.

```
svg.select('#' + uniqueid + '-flare')
                    .select('path')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)');
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Update

Lars asked to see some more code. So.... (It is very abridged)

```
var dragtype, dragsum;
var wordDrag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(Object)
        .on('drag', function (d) {

            if(dragType != d.word) {
                dragType = d.word;
                dragSum = 0;
            } 

            //update current position
            dragSum = dragSum + parseInt(d3.event.dx);
            var xMovement = parseInt(this.getAttribute('x')) + parseInt(d3.event.dx);

            d3.select(this)
                .attr('class', 'dragged-points')
                .attr('x', xMovement);

                if(uniqueId == d.word) {                   
                    svg.select('#' + uniqueId + '-flare')
                        .select('path')
                        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + dragSum + ',0)');
                }
            }
        });    

word.selectAll('text')
        .data(data)
      .enter().append('text')
        .attr('class', 'points')
        .attr('id', ... )
        .attr('x', ...)
        .attr('y', ...)
        .call(wordDrag);

tick = setInterval(function(){
        animate();
    }, 1000);

 function animate() {
        word.transition()
           .duration(1000)
           .ease('linear')
           .attr('x', ...)
           .attr('y', ...);

        svg.select('#' + uniqueId + '-flare')
           .select('path')
           .transition().duration(1000)
           .ease('linear')
           .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)');
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: Ya I will add more code, but what browser are you adding. My research seemed to imply that it might be a broswer issue where firefox reads 'translate(0,0)' as 'translate(0)' although, I am also having the same problem on Chrome so maybe this isn't the problem.

Comment: Or perhaps it is the fact that sometimes 'translate(0,0)' is called even when no other transformation has been applied to the path.

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `parseInt` on `d3.event.dx`. And the point of me asking was so that I could actually try it, which I can't with the abbreviated code. Could you put something on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) perhaps?

Comment: Hmm that would be pretty cumbersome, it is a pretty big project. I am going to tinker around a bit more first.

Comment: It might help if you create a custom tween to tell it how to interpolate between the different translations.